# Embedding index in pdf files

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, hashing

Are there any (free) tools for building an index of a pdf and embedding it in the file in order to speed up searching?

I know Acrobat Pro has a [catalog option](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WSC28D4DBB-6A78-4027-9E04-F50FE411CFB9.w.html) but I was hoping for a free tool and multiplatform tool.

Comment: Just found that DocFetch (amongst others) can catalogue pdf files. This serves the purpose even if the catalogue is not enbedded in the pdf.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed.  The solution for Acrobat is Advanced > Document Processing > Manage Embedded Index ->  Embed Index, and save it.  What I don't know is how to do it automatically for all pdf files.